# Can I tell scala.xml to match any of two tags?

Tags: scala, scala-xml

`body \\ "div"` matches the "div" tags, and `body \\ "p"` matches the "p" tags.

But what if I'd like to match all the "div" and "p" tags? Is it possible with one expression in scala.xml?

And if not, is there another way to iterate over all the "div" and "p" tags in the document in the order in which they appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the source for `\\` in [NodeSeq.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/NodeSeq.scala) you can see that it's really just a bit of sugar for a `filter` operation over `descendant_or_self`, which is a `List[Node]`, using the node's `label`.

So you could do the same thing yourself, matching against a *set* of labels, like this:

```
val searchedLabels = Set("p", "div")

val results = body.descendant_or_self.filter(node => searchedLabels.contains(node.label))
```

---

Or if you really want it to seem like "built-in" functionality, you can pimp-on a suitable method to `scala.xml.Node` like so:

```
class ExtendedNode(n: Node) {

  def \\\(labels: Set[String]): NodeSeq = {
    n.descendant_or_self.filter(node => labels.contains(node.label))
  }
}

implicit def node2extendedNode(n: Node): ExtendedNode = new ExtendedNode(n)

val results = body \\\ Set("p", "div")
```

although I must say I'm not sure I like either the method-name or the use of an implicit here :-(

Comment: Please, can yo explain why you do not like the use of implicit here?

Comment: Just a personal preference. I find that (in general) implicits are not well-understood and/or can be difficult to reason about when browsing a new codebase. This particular style, i.e. "object pimping", while making the application-site very neat, is just a little too obscure/magic for my taste. If this was my code, I'd probably just *explicitly* wrap `body` in a `new ExtendedNode`.

Comment: Got your point and, apart some special case, I agree now that you remarked this. Thank you